# Basic Javascript Object/Form Access

Tags: javascript

I was looking at some sample code tutorials and noticed that on Javascript-coder.com, the author has several entries about form access which use two different methods of accessing form elements without explanation.

Example:

```
var myForm = document.forms["myForm"];
var elem = myForm[anInputName];
//OR
var myForm = document.forms["myForm"];
var elem = myForm.elements[anInputName];
```

Both appear to provide valid access to the element. Google just seems to crap out a bunch of syntax references. Why do both work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript forms have the [elements collection](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/coll_form_elements.asp) which is an array of all form elements, but JS will also allow you to access the form elements by object key, as in your first example above.

Comment: Is there any reason to go with one or the other, or is it personal style?

Comment: Completely down to personal choice, both are equally valid and point to the same objects. Personally I'd pick the 1st method as it's a tiny bit less to code.

Comment: The "elements" array property provides the ability to easily loop through elements of a form, looping through object properties in javascript can be a bit more complicated.